# Why ObjectMapperr does not write values to file?

Tags: java, json, file, jackson

I wrote a method that gets JSON, converts an object to java and writes JSON to a file.But writing to the file just does not work. Tell me what could be the reason?

```
public class ApiUtils {


public static HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

public static void getRequest(String url, String path) {
    PostDTO postDTO = new PostDTO();
    String pathJSONFile = "src/main/resources/Post.json";
    List<PostPojo> postPojos = null;


    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .GET()
            .header("accept", "application/json")
            .uri(URI.create(url + path))
            .build();

    try {
        HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        postPojos = objectMapper.readValue(response.body(), new TypeReference<List<PostPojo>>() {
        });
        objectMapper.writeValue(Paths.get("allPost.json").toFile(), response.body());
        postDTO.setStatus(response.statusCode());
        postDTO.setPosts(postPojos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(postDTO);

}
}
```

File allPost.json located in the folder resources.

Answer (score -1):

You're writing the wrong object I think - your code sample says

```
objectMapper.writeValue(Paths.get("allPost.json").toFile(), response.body());
```

which is trying to write the `InputStream` of response.body(). I *presume* you meant to try and write out `postPojos` via

```
objectMapper.writeValue(Paths.get("allPost.json").toFile(), postPojos);
```

instead.

Comment: No, it still doesn’t add it. I’m thinking, maybe you need to add the path to the file?